# Get labeled files from TFS using Ant

Tags: java, ant, tfs

I need to get labeled files from TFS server to another work space by using the Ant script. Basically I need to build a Java project. I have tried the below build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test-teamprise-ant-tasks" basedir="C:/EARs/TFS" default="deploy">
    <tstamp/>
    <record name="log/build.log.${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}" action="start" loglevel="verbose" append="true"/>
    <property name="ant.lib.dir" value="C:/ant/lib"/> 
    <property name="tfs.server" value="http://tfsververurl:8080/tfs" />
    <property name="tfs_workspace_name" value="TFSWORKSPCENAME"/>
    <property name="tfs_project_name" value="$/PROJECT/CODE"/> 
    <typedef resource="com/teamprise/ant/antlib.xml" 
        classpath="${ant.lib.dir}/teamprise-ant-1.2.jar" />

    <target name="diagnostics">
        <tfstasksdiagnostics />
    </target> 
    <target name="get" description="get the codes">
        <echo message="Get latest source code from tfs"/>     
        <tfsget localpath="${basedir}/src" force="false" />
        <tfsget localpath="${basedir}/WebRoot" force="false" />
    </target>
    <target name="deploy" depends="get" description=" get the codes,compile,package and deploy the output file">
        <ant antfile="qk.xml"
            dir="${basedir}"
            inheritall="false"
            inheritrefs="false"
            target="war"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I am getting the below issue:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type tfsget
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:481)
```

I am also trying to find the **teamprise-ant-1.2.jar** from the Internet. I am not able to get it.
Please help me to resolve this issue or suggest to me how to manage the build with TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [acquired Teamprise in 2009](https://news.microsoft.com/2009/11/09/microsoft-acquires-teamprise-assets-provides-cross-platform-support-for-visual-studio/). The teamprise.com web site doesn't appear to be available anymore so it may be difficult to find a copy of teamprise-ant-1.2.jar.

A copy of [the older teamprise-ant-1.1.jar](https://web.archive.org/web/20070922033842/http://www.teamprise.com/download/download-ant.html) is available thanks to the Internet Archive Wayback Machine. Even though it's an older version, it supports the `<tfsget>` task. Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thaks a lot Chad..I can able to get the teamprise-ant-1.1.jar but still build is failing getting the below issue.I am completely new to TFS and ANT..kindly help me.   [tfsget] tf get C:\TFS_Label\src -recursive
   [tfsget] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:     BUILD FAILED
C:\ant\Release13\build.xml:15: tf failed - see above for any failure messages (i
f redirecting output, you may need to set the logerror attribute to true)